# Grouping of Pandas Dataframe by season

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to group the dataframe by Season (dry and wet season). My dry season extends from Nov-Apr and Wet season from May-Oct. I have tried to write this python script.

```
 def GroupFunc(x):
   return SeasonDict[x.month]

SeasonDict={10:'Wet',11:'Dry',12:'Dry',1:'Dry',2:'Dry',3:'Dry',4:'Dry',5:'Wet',6:'Wet',7:'Wet',8:'Wet',9:'Wet'}

obs_group=obs_data.groupby(GroupFunc)
get_grp=obs_group.get_group('Dry')
```

Now I am trying to calculate the sum based on season

```
  dry_avg=(get_grp.groupby(get_grp.index.year).sum())
```

If I group by year, I am missing some of the months for dry season. For example if I am considering year 2015 and 2016

Sum of Dry season rainfall for year 2016 should be the sum of the Months :

```
 Nov-Dec (2015) + Jan-Apr (2016) = Dry season sum
```

I am expecting the way to solve this issue in grouping.

Comment: You should add an extra column to your DataFrame indicating the "water year" and use that instead of the calendar year.

Comment: Thanks BrenBam for your reply. But can you explain how can I add water year in the data frame.

Comment: That's a question you have to answer yourself based on your data.  Presumably you just want some logic that says "if the month is November or December, add 1 to the calendar year to get the water year, otherwise use the calendar year".  But you have to decide if Nov 2015 is "water year 2015" or "water year 2016".

Comment: I have tried like this :

dry_avg=(get_grp.groupby(get_grp.index.shift(-2,freq='m').year).sum()).

I think from this also I got what i expected @BrenBarn